# Downgrade node version 10.7.0 to 10.6.0 using brew

Tags: node.js, homebrew

I had recently upgraded my node from v8.0.0 to v10.7.0. I actually need v10.6.0. I know it's strange but that's what my environment wants.

I googled how to downgrade but it seems the information is about being able to change it to a completely different version like from 10.7.0 back to 8.0.0 but nothing from 10.7.0 to 10.6.0.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should really look into [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md) it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OS's package managers often do not allow for installing specific versions of a package. They focus on stability.

I would use the [n package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) like this:

```
$ sudo npm -g install n
$ n 10.6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Install nvm via brew then install any node versions you want. Use nvm to switch between